# CListCtrl CScrollBar

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I need to set custom width of the ScrollBar  in CListCtrl Class. How can I do this? May be this method need to use? And how to use?

```
CListCtrl::GetScrollBarCtrl()::SetWindowPos(...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just do that by calling one function. Here is the example how to change width of scrollbar in MFC application, it should help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1810/ResizeScrollbar-How-to-change-width-of-built-in-sc